# Can not create SQLite database on mac (permission) issues

Tags: java, macos, sqlite, permissions, file-permissions

I am trying to added an application folder to the **Application Support** folder on Mac. It works, but I can not write to the folder. when I do `ls -l` on the folder I get: `drwxr-xr-x`, but for some reason I can not create the `db` file there.

```
String OS = (System.getProperty("os.name")).toUpperCase();
String location;
if(OS.contains("WIN")){
    location = "/" + System.getenv("APPDATA").replace("\\", "/") + "/Phantom";
}else{
    location = System.getProperty("user.home");
    location += "/Library/Application Support/Phantom";
}
File f = new File(location);
if(!f.isDirectory()){
    f.mkdir();
}
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:" + location + "/phantom.db");
```

First off, this is the right place to store this information on mac right? Assuming so, what should I be doing so that this works?

**Edit Trace:**

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sqlite/NativeDB
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1929)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1814)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
        at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1083)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:200)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.extractAndLoadLibraryFile(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:148)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.loadSQLiteNativeLibrary(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:249)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteJDBCLoader.initialize(SQLiteJDBCLoader.java:65)
        at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.load(NativeDB.java:53)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:136)
        at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:66)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:21)
        at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
        at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:44)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:113)
        at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:87)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at phantom.SQLite.connect(SQLite.java:46)
        at phantom.SQLite.getUsers(SQLite.java:123)
        at phantom.Browser.loadCustomPage(Browser.java:194)
        at phantom.Main.start(Main.java:29)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.NativeDB
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 30 more
Exception running application phantom.Main
```

Comment: the folder may be drwxr-xr-x, but what user are you running this code as? Since the folder's 755, only the OWNER has write permissions on it. if you're runninga as a different user, then you don't have write permissions.

Comment: I am using Netbeans to build and execute the file, I assume it uses the current user to build the project, run the project, and create the folder...

Comment: Try `chmod 777 "~/Library/App...../Phantom"` temporarily to see if that helps.

Comment: so then whatever user YOU'RE logged in as and running netbeans would have to be the owner of that folder as well.

Comment: @MarkSetchell after doing that, I am still not able to create the database db file...

Comment: I tried escaping the space in `Application Support`, it is still broken...

Comment: Could you include a stack trace?

Comment: @woot I have added the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows...

```
NoClassDefFoundError: org/sqlite/NativeDB
```

I think you may have downloaded the wrong jar with the wrong native libraries embedded. Try the one [here](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) and follow the OSX directions (just regarding setting the classpath really).

Comment: The code works on windows though, and it is the library that I am already using.

Comment: It isn't the code.  It's the sqlite jar file.  The jar contains embedded native code.  If you copied the jar, and that jar does not have OSX native code, it will fail with this error.

Comment: Like I said that is already the Library I am using, so the native code should already be there...

Comment: Do you have two sqlite jars in your classpath maybe where one is the Windows version?

Comment: I figured it out! I just needed to use an older version of the driver and It worked fine. Thanks